# Cannot import to_categorical from keras in Google Colab

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

So i have been working on a notebook on Google Colab, and all of a sudden i get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bd6ec74ccf2e> in <module>()
----> 1 from keras.utils import to_categorical

ImportError: cannot import name 'to_categorical' from 'keras.utils' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
```

It's very strange since it was working just fine, and when i restarted my session, this happened. I tried with another google account too (in case there might be something wrong with my account's setup), but i still got the same error.

This is what i use to import the function.

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
```

I'm wondering if anything change, and if anyone else experiences the same issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from TF 2.0, it's been moved with tensorflow. please use this way:

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
to_categorical([0, 1, 2, 3], num_classes=4)
```

result will be like

```
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_train_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
```

remove this line from your code and use this

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
```

this will solve your problem